# Putting a word in a column in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut to put a word in a column in VSCode?

So for example if we have:

`hello` and we want:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

There's a demo of it here (I think this is Sublime):

https://youtu.be/m1ZKHPbnyjo?t=43

Comment: Place Multi cursor - use a regex find for `.`, Select all (Alt+Enter), Enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as hinted at by rioV8 in the comments, the way to do it is to create multiple cursors within the word.

This can be done with `alt-click` or `option-click` (Mac) and then once there is a cursor in front of each letter we can hit enter and all the letters are moved to a separate line.